# Damn it, Perl can't bless my object

Tags: perl, bless

Puns aside, I'm trying to implement an `import` method in my Perl class to instantiate a `Data` object, which is essentially a glorified array of hashrefs, from a proper array of hashrefs.

Here's an example of how I plan to use it:

```
# Pull in the data
my $data = Data->import(
                         [
                           { a => 1, b => 7, c => 3},
                           { a => 7, b => 9, c => 2},
                         ]
                       );

$data->manipulate;  # Use package methods
```

---

My `import` implementation is as follows:

```
package Data;

sub initialize {
    my $class = shift;
    my $data = [];
    bless $data, $class;
    return $data;
}

sub import {

    my ( $class, $data ) = @_;

    bless $data, $class;
    return $data;
}

1;
```

The surprising thing is that Perl reports the error *at **compile**-time* (note the `BEGIN` block):

```
Can't bless non-reference value at Data.pm line 51.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at myScript.pl line 8.
```

[`perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) didn't add much clarity to what's going on:

> **Can't bless non-reference value**
>
> `(F)` Only hard references may be blessed. This is how Perl "enforces"
>   encapsulation of objects. See
>   [`perlobj`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html).

---

I even tried initializing the object and adding the data in two separate steps:

```
sub import {                         #< Another constructor >

    my ( $class, $data ) = @_;

    my $obj = $class->initialize;
    push @$obj, @$data;

    return $obj;
}
```

This resulted in the following compile-time error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference...
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at...
```

---

Two questions:

1. What's wrong with what I've done?
2. Could someone please clarify the `perldiag` explanation of this compile-time error?

Comment: Hindsight : Is there any better reference than `perldiag` to understand warning/error messages?

Comment: In general, you can attack errors like this by inserting a print of your preconditions.  In this case, the arguments to your subroutine. (`print "import got: @_\n";`) That would have let you know that what you thought was an array actually wasn't.  Next, add a guard, something like `ref $data eq 'ARRAY' or confess "not an array: '$data'";` and you will find out where the offending call is coming from. (`confess` is from `use Carp 'confess';` and provides a full backtrace)  Keep that line in, as it may help you immediately catch other errors in the future, perhaps changing `confess` to `croak`.

Comment: @Lance Roberts : The original title was a play on words in reference to  the [`Acme::Damn`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme::Damn) module (which does the opposite of `bless`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

import() is a dangerous name to give a method, as Perl sometimes calls a method called 'import' for you.  In fact, the statement:

```
use Data;
```

really means:

```
BEGIN {
    require Data;
    Data->import();
}
```

which happens during 'compilation'.

So it's likely that your import() method is being called by Perl as part of the class loading mechanism before you get a chance to use it.  You should rename your import() method to something else (e.g. import_data) and you should be fine.

Comment: If that were the case, he wouldn't be getting the error he's getting.

Comment: Yes, he would.  In both cases Perl would call Data->import(), so $data never exists, causing the 'no object to bless' error, and the 'no array to dereference' error.

Comment: +1 : This was the issue, renamed `import` to `load`. My sanity has been restored. Thanks!

Comment: I have always thought that the `import` method should be the `IMPORT` method to go along with `DESTROY` and other language blocks like `BEGIN`. The user/programmer doesn't expect that an all lower case declaration of a method would a) have a different meaning than any other and b) cause this problem.